# Responsive HTML5 navbar with centered logo "popping" out

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to build a responsive navbar like in the picture below for the desktop version and, in the mobile version, I want it to transform into a drop-down burger-menu. I also want the logo to "pop" outside of it and cover a bit of the content under the navbar.

[navbar with logo "popping" out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z2xYn.png)

I'm a beginner so I was thinking about modifying a bootstrap navbar to suit my needs but I have the following struggles:

1. I don't know how to center the content and keep it responsive (I don't mind if the logo is visible inside the burger-menu in the mobile version).
2. I don't know how to make the logo "pop" outside the navbar and cover a bit of the content under it
3. I haven't got to the part that displays and colors in red the active tab but I need some help for that too

I would really appreciate if someone has the time to read this post and give me a hand or some advice.

Below you can see my code so far but I'm not sure how good it is.
I wish you all a good day :)

```css
#menu-wrapper {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.4) !important;
}


#burger-menu {
  color: #fbf9ff;
}

#nav-container {
text-align: center;
margin:0 auto;
display: inline-block;
position:fixed;
width:100%;
height:15%;
background:#c73a30;
}
.logo{
  top:-65px !important;
  height:150px !important;
  line-height:150px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>navbar</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>


<section id="nav-container">
  <nav id="menu-wrapper" class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-dark bg-inverse">
      <div class="navbar-header">
          <button id="burger-menu" class="navbar-toggler hidden-sm-up pull-xs-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-controls="navbar" aria-expanded="false">
              &#9776;
          </button>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-toggleable-xs pull-sm-right" id="navbar">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#about-me">COMEDIANS</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#web-development">EVENTS</a>
              </li>
              <div class="logo">
                <img src="http://www.battleoftastings.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/seafood-placeholder150x150px.png"/>
              </div>
              <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#gallery">GET IN TOUCH</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#gallery">GALLERY</a>
              </li>
          </ul>
      </div>
  </nav>
</section>



<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't know any bootstrap so I am going to be suggesting pure CSS3 solutions. First of all, you need to create a media query like this:

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {

}
```

This will tell CSS3 that if the window width is less than 600px, run some code. @media code will overwrite any existing code. For a more in-depth explanation, look up any @media tutorials. There are plenty tutorials explaining how to use @media queries properly.

Question #1:

A simple `text-align:center;` in your @media query should be enough.

Question #2:
Here you need a copy of the image. You can place that copy wherever you want. Give an id to the copy as you will need to hide it. Then put `display:none;` in the id. If you did it correctly, you should the get this result:

```
#logocopy {
    display:none;
}
```

Then in your @media query set the copy of the image to `display:block;` while set the image in the navbar to `display:none;`. If you did it correctly, you should get this result:

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
   .logo {
       display:none;
   }
   #logoCopy {
       display: block;
   }
}
```

If you want to center your image just do this: #logoCopy `{margin: 0 auto;}`. Do that in the media query of course. If everything is done correctly, your image should be able to jump out of navbar. Now if you want for your image to cover some text, you will have to edit the image's wrap points.

Question #3:
This one is also quite simple, all you have to do is give it an id of "active" to first li (assuming you are on the first page) (the name of the id can be anything) and then code this:

```
#active {
    background-color: red;
}
```

If you have put your id in the correct place, it should look like this:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-toggleable-xs pull-sm-right" id="navbar">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li class="nav-item" id="active">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#about-me">COMEDIANS</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#web-development">EVENTS</a>
              </li>
              <div class="logo">
                <img src="http://www.battleoftastings.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/seafood-placeholder150x150px.png"/>
              </div>
              <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#gallery">GET IN TOUCH</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#gallery">GALLERY</a>
              </li>
          </ul>
      </div>
```

Hope this helps!